# Sign-in with Google API: How to get gender, birthday and city in 2022?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-php-client

I have a **Sign-in with Google API** integration that has been **approved** by Google and is currently **working**. Other than the basic information, I would also like to obtain **gender**, **birthday** and **city**.

Here's an example of an oauth response I get from Google when logging-in a user:

```
Google\Service\Oauth2\Userinfo Object ( [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( [familyName] => family_name [givenName] => given_name [verifiedEmail] => verified_email ) [email] => contact@xxxxxxxxxxx.com [familyName] => xxxxxxxx [gender] => [givenName] => xxxxxx [hd] => xxxxxxxxxxx.com [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [link] => https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [locale] => en [name] => xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx [picture] => https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [verifiedEmail] => 1 [modelData:protected] => Array ( [verified_email] => 1 [given_name] => xxxxxx [family_name] => xxxxxxxxxx ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

*note that the gender this user is already set to public in his Google account (still, the gender field appears to be blank).

My questions are:

1. Is it still possible in 2022?
2. Can I do it with the sign-in with Google API or with some other API? (involving multiple requests)
3. What scopes do I need to set in  the Google Cloud Console oauth section?
4. Is there any PHP working example / documentation?

Unfortunately, I did not find any good official/unofficial (and recent) documentation/tutorials related to my use-case. Anyone knows the best approach to follow here?

Answer (score 0):

To get a users gender and birthday information you go though the People api

The [people.get method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22genders%2Cbirthdays%22%7D) will return this information

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/d200475532672775346",
  "etag": "%EgUBBwguNxoEAQIFByIMR3BzQkR2cnI1ZGc9",
  "genders": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "d200475532672775346"
        }
      },
      "value": "female",
      "formattedValue": "Female"
    }
  ],
  "birthdays": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "d200475532672775346"
        }
      },
      "date": {
        "month": 1,
        "day": 6
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "ACCOUNT",
          "id": "d200475532672775346"
        }
      },
      "date": {
        "year": 1971,
        "month": 1,
        "day": 6
      }
    }
  ]
}
```